# Confused with Euclidean distance and radius

Tags: computer-science, euclidean-geometry, exponentiation, inner-products, radicals

I have N points in D dimensions and a query point `q` in D dimensions. I have to check if the points lie in Euclidean distance less than a given radius `r`. So I can do:

```
for every point p:
  check if Euclidean_dist(p, q) < r
```

However, I must do this in a computer program with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and the Euclidean distance requires a *square root* which is very time-costly for a computer.

Would this be equivalent?

```
for every point p:
  check if squared_Euclidean_dist(p, q) < r²
```

Note that 'squared_Euclidean_dist()' won't square root the dot product.

Comment: Basically, yes. That's equivalent to $a,b \ge 0 \implies \big( a \lt b \iff a^2 \lt b^2\big)$.

Comment: You are correct, you can save the square root by doing the comparison to $r^2$ as you suggest.  Possible $r^2$ can be computed just once for all the $N$ points you want to check.

Comment: @hardmath yeah that's what I have in mind, compute once the squared radius. I see dxiv thanks. So can someone post an answer? ;)

Comment: I use this same optimization whenever I can.

Comment: Yeah @David K me too, I am just solving this kind of problem for first time, that's why I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be mathematically equivalent, since:

$$a,b \ge 0 \quad \implies\quad \big( a \lt b \iff  a^2 <b^2\big)$$

Computation-wise it may be worth noting that the squared distance will have a different range, and (at the ends of the range) possibly different precision also, compared to the distance itself.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this is true, but make sure you have your numerical accuracy in place.

E.g. for very small $a$, you could have $a^2 = 0$. Or for very large $a$, you could have overflow on $a^2$.